# Unable to figure out how to loop a css animation in KreatureMedia Layerslider

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, plugins

So I'm using KreatureMedias Layerslider and I have a fullwidth wave I want to have bob up and down.

At the moment I have this...

```
<img class="ls-layer" data-ls="durationin:1500;scalein:1.1;offsetxin:-50;loopcount:-1;loopoffsetx:0sw;loopoffsety:1sh;loopduration:600;" src="/img/wave2.png" style="left: 0px; top: 75%; width: 100%; height: auto;" />
```

It does technically loop but the issue is that it animates up a few pixels before jumping back to its original location. What I want is for it to animate up a few pixels and then animate back to its starting position.

How would I go about doing this?

I know how to do it in pure CSS but was hoping someone might know the method to do it through Layerslider.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, you can add loopyoyo:true to the element.

```
<img class="ls-layer" data-ls="durationin:1500;scalein:1.1;offsetxin:-50;loopcount:-1;loopoffsetx:0sw;loopoffsety:1sh;loopduration:800;loopyoyo:true;" src="/img/wave3.png" style="left: 0px; top: 70%; width: 100%; height: auto;" />
```